# Swift - UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath & didDeselectRowAtIndexPath Add & Remove indexPath IDs

Tags: ios, uitableview, select, swift, deselect

This is the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedItem = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
    let itemId = selectedItem.componentsSeparatedByString("$%^")
    //itemId[1] - Item Id
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedItem = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
    let itemId = selectedItem.componentsSeparatedByString("$%^")
    //itemId[1] - Item Id
}
```

How to add Item Id "in Array or in String or something else..."? When you select rows 0,1,4,5 for example you have different Item Ids added "in Array or in String" and then when I want to deselect them how to deselect exact Item Id from the indexPath.row that is deselected and find it "in Array or in String or something else..." and deleted it ?
Sorry for my broken english if you have a questions ask in comments and I will explain if I can

Comment: I need to search in array or string for this ID which is deselected and I want to remove it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could do this pretty simply by adding a `Dictionary` property to your table view controller:

```swift
class ViewController : UITableViewController {
    var selectedItems: [String: Bool] = [:]

    // ...

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
        let itemId = selectedItem.componentsSeparatedByString("$%^")
        // add to self.selectedItems
        selectedItems[itemId[1]] = true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
        let itemId = selectedItem.componentsSeparatedByString("$%^")
        // remove from self.selectedItems
        selectedItems[itemId[1]] = nil
    }

    // can access the items as self.selectedItems.keys
    func doSomething() {
        for item in selectedItems.keys {
            println(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a mistake :)
var selectedItems = Dictionary<String, Bool>()

Comment: When I use your var Xcode outputs me an error.. I don't know :)

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to use `indexPathsForSelectedRows`?

Answer (score 6):

For Swift 3.0, use

```
override  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt
 indexPath: IndexPath){
     //your code...  
}
```